# Jest resolver cannot find a file which path ressembles existing node modules

Tags: jestjs

I have upgraded jest from version **27** to version **29**.

Since then, some indirect file resolve do not work anymore.

Here is my config:

```js
module.exports = {
  roots: ['app/javascript/__tests__/'],
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2',
  moduleDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    'app/javascript',
    'app/javascript/__tests__'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/app/javascript/__tests__/fileMock.js'
  },
  setupFiles: ['./app/javascript/__tests__/setup.jsx']
}
```

There is a file in my code base, let's say `app/javascript/MyReactComponent.jsx`, which is imported as part of my tested component, and that contains the following import line:

```js
// app/javascript/MyReactComponent.jsx
import 'firebase/init'
```

**Expected behavior**

Until today, I could run jest, and it was finding all my code as expected, inclluding the above import, which is located here:

```
app/javascript/firebase/init.js
```

**Error**

Instead, running jest throws the following error.

```bash
Cannot find module 'firebase/init' from 'app/javascript/MyReactComponent.jsx'
```

---

*FWIW, I have traced the resolver code up to the default jest resolver, and it seems like it tries to get the file from within the `firebase` node **module**, instead of fetching the `init.js` file in the `firebase` **directory**.*

**Question**

Is there a way to adjust my configuration in order for the resolver to find my file?

Comment: Add another entry in `moduleNameMapper` pointing to the init location.

Comment: Thanks @morganney, that's funny I was just trying that! And it works to load `init.js`, but **then** within that file, some dependencies are imported from the actual `firebase/database` module, which should be found in `node_modules/firebase/database` but because of the `moduleNameMapper` it does not work anymore :'( Webpack and Jest <28 do not have any problems with that.

Comment: I guess I can _exclude_ the real firebase modules from the mapper? Or specify each file instead of the whole `firebase` folder, but that's a bit hacky... I wish I could just find the resolver config that was working before.

Comment: You should show more of your code setup, webpack, jest, source files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an entry for that aliased module in `moduleNameMapper`?

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(svg)$': '<rootDir>/app/javascript/__tests__/fileMock.js',
    '^firebase/init': '<rootDir>/app/javascript/firebase/init.js'
  }
```

Comment: This works but it means I have to add a config entry for each file in `firebase` folder, which is not very convenient now, nor in the future when test will fail each time someone adds a file there.

Comment: Why not use globs?

Comment: I cannot do `firebase/*` as it would match legit node modules such as `firebase/database`, if this is what you had in mind?